# How automate build number & app version of react-native ios app based on git-tag?

Tags: react-native

What I want to do is automating build number & app version of ios app based on git-tag. Previous native ios project, I automate build number of app using this script :

```
## Refer to https://www.mokacoding.com/blog/automatic-xcode-versioning-with-git/

git=$(sh /etc/profile; which git)
number_of_commits=$("$git" rev-list HEAD --count)
git_release_version=$("$git" describe --tags --always --abbrev=0)


target_plist="$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$INFOPLIST_PATH"
dsym_plist="$DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH/$DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME/Contents/Info.plist"

for plist in "$target_plist" "$dsym_plist"; do
echo "plist :: $plist"
if [ -f "$plist" ]; then
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $number_of_commits" "$plist"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleShortVersionString ${git_release_version#*v}" "$plist"
fi
done
```

but, in react native app, not working! 
While debuging, I found that `target_plist` & `dsym_plist` is not exist.

How do I make it work on React Native App?

Comment: u must see git CI/CD for that